# Get the number of compositions with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

The number of compositions of $n$ is $2^{n-1}$.

For $n=5$, the number of compositions is $2^{5-1}=16$

- **5**
- 4 + 1
- **3 + 2**
- 3 + 1 + 1
- **2 + 3**
- 2 + 2 + 1
- 2 + 1 + 2
- 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
- 1 + 4
- 1 + 3 + 1
- 1 + 2 + 2
- 1 + 2 + 1 + 1
- 1 + 1 + 3
- 1 + 1 + 2 + 1
- 1 + 1 + 1 + 2
- 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

What if I want only the count for compositions where all the parts are greater than a value $k$ ($k=2$ in my example, and the kept compositions are the bold ones) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion for the unrestricted compositions is:

$F_0=1$ and $F_n=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} F_j$, it is easy to show with induction that this is equal to $2^{n-1}$.

The recursion for the "restricted" compositions in which every block is in $[a,b]$ is $F_0=1$ and $F_n=\sum\limits_{j=a}^{\min(n,b)}F_{n-j}$. This allows you to get $F_n$ in time $\mathcal O(n(b-a+1) )$, I don't know if this is fast enough.

some c++ code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=10010; // size of array
int F[MAX]; // this array stores the results

int main(){
    int a,b,n;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&n); // this takes the input of a,b,n
    F[0]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){// we recursively udate the value
        for(int j=a;j<=b && j<=i;j++){
            F[i]+=F[i-j]; // we add F[i-j] to F[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",F[n]); //prints the result
}
```